# d3.js Forcing Nodes away from bounding box

Tags: d3.js

I am currently working on a project where I need to keep the nodes of a force simulation away from the svg edges.
My attempt was using a exponential curve to increase the centering force for nodes reaching a certain x coordinate.
I am using this function [image: Math Function]

```js
function getBorderForce(x, width, middle, steepness = 10) {
        return Math.pow(((x-middle)/(width/2)), steepness)
    }
```

If the given `x` value reaches `middle + width / 2` it returns a value of `1`. The steepness of the increase can modified by `steepness` parameter. A higher value means the nodes would get repealed *later*. I hope it is understandable.

I would then implement this function as follows into a `d3.forceSimulation()`:

```js
 const sim = d3.forceSimulation().
    .force("forceX", d3.forceX().x(d => d.forceX).strength(0.02))
    .force("forceY", d3.forceY().y(d => d.forceY).strength(0.1))
    .force("edgeRepeal", d3.forceX().x(_ => center).strength(d => 
         getBorderForce(d.x, width, center)
    ))
    .nodes(nodes)
```

When I use this approach my browser crashes and I get an out of memory error.
It works is if I use the `d.forceX` instead of the `d.x` value, but that means that nodes closer to the edges would be pushed in and would not be placed on their desired position `d.forceX`.
Maybe someone has a better idea or can show the flaw in my code – I am relatively new to d3, so it would be no surprise.

All the Best

Comment: I'm not sure the D3 Force layout can satisfy your requirements. Did you try to build a layout of your own (just calculate `x` and `y` for each node you render)?

Comment: No, never done that. Some starting points? ty